# How can I draw with my current brush size in gimp python-fu?

Tags: python, gimp, python-fu

I'm writing a GIMP python-fu script that essentially just draws a black circle on the current layer, filling up the layer. The problem I'm having is that gimp_pencil() continues to use the default brush size even after gimp_context_set_brush_size() sets the active brush size to the size of the image (when I run the script from GIMP, the brush size slider changes to the width of the layer, but the mark that is made remains the default of 50x50)
Here's my code:

```
def Circle(image, tdrawable):
    layer  = image.active_layer
    width  = tdrawable.width
    height = tdrawable.height
    pdb.gimp_context_set_brush_size(width)
    pdb.gimp_pencil(layer,2,(width/2,height/2))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would you mind adding your GIMP version?

Comment: This seens to work in GIMP git master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seens to work in the current development version of GIMP (compiled from GIT master) - if you are hang this behavior on the latest GIMP stable (2.8.14) you've hit a program bug.

However, this is a hacky way to draw a circle, even if it works (ok if you wnat to use it for other brushes rather than circular ones) - but for circles, you should instead: 
1) Make an ellipse selection centered on the image center and with radius min(width, layer)/2
2) Fill the selection.

Comment: That seemed to do it, Thanks! Probably banged my head over this a bit too long, thinking it was something I did. 

And yes, I'm planning on using other brushes besides just circles to do some generative art.